# Grouping and substituting

Tags: c#, linq, select, group-by

I'm looking to group line patterns whose length is 10 or more characters. I then need to substitute repetitions with a string. I currently hold these line patterns in a string array called 'lines' and pass them through this code:

```
var grp = lines
    .GroupBy(g => g)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1 && x.Key.Length > 10)
    .Select(s => new { Key = s.Key, Count = s.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Count);
```

I then manually iterate through the Dictionary items and eliminate repetitions. Unofrtunately, if my initial data is very large, this could take some time. Is there a way to make the above LINQ expression do that for me? In other words, instead of counting instances, simply replace them with a string I give it?

1st EDIT:

Initial input:

```
Joe comes to dinner 
Frank goes to work 
Frank goes to work 
Joe comes to dinner 
Joe comes to dinner 
Tammy goes to the gym 
Frank goes to work 
Tammy goes to the gym 
Frank goes to work 
Frank goes to work
```

Now I get something like:

```
<Joe comes to dinner><3> 
<Frank goes to work><5> 
<Tammy goes to the gym><2>
```

What I'd like is to substitute all repetitions (leaving the first occurrence intact) in the original array with a string, say, "REPETITION!":

```
Joe comes to dinner 
Frank goes to work 
REPETITION! 
REPETITION! 
REPETITION! 
Tammy goes to the gym 
REPETITION! 
REPETITION! 
REPETITION! 
REPETITION!
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input with actual output and expected output?

Comment: Initial input:

Joe comes to dinner
Frank goes to work
Frank goes to work
Joe comes to dinner
Joe comes to dinner
Tammy goes to the gym
Frank goes to work
Tammy goes to the gym
Frank goes to work
Frank goes to work

Now I get something like:

<Joe comes to dinner><3>
<Frank goes to work><5>
<Tammy goes to the gym><2>

I want to substitute the repetitions in the original array with the string "REPETITION!":

Joe comes to dinner
Frank goes to work
REPETITION!
REPETITION!
REPETITION!
Tammy goes to the gym
REPETITION!
REPETITION!
REPETITION!
REPETITION!

Comment: Please _edit_ your question with the sample data. It's unreadable as a comment...

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without `GroupBy`. You could iterate over the List and replace the words if already encountered the word before. For example

```
var result = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var str in lines)
{
    var wordToAdd = result.Contains(str) ? "REPETITION":str;
    result.Add(wordToAdd);
}
```

Output

```
Joe comes to dinner 
Frank goes to work 
REPETITION 
REPETITION 
REPETITION 
Tammy goes to the gym 
REPETITION 
REPETITION 
REPETITION 
REPETITION
```

Comment: Use a hash set to keep track of repetitions or it will get exponentially slower as the list grows.

Comment: @Slothario Thanks for pointing out. Have updated the answer with HashSet

Comment: You'll still need a way to either write wordToAdd, either to a final list, or even better some kind of filebuffer. But I suppose that's implied.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `HashSet<string>` to filter out duplicates (not a `List<string>`, which would be slower; lookup in a `List` is O(n), and in a `HashSet` is O(1)).

If you insist on using a LINQ expression, then it would look like this (assuming `data` is the initial string containing all the lines)

```cs
var seen = new HashSet<string>();
IEnumerable<string> replaced =
    from line in data.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    select seen.Add(line) ? line : "REPETITION";
foreach (string line in replaced)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

But more realistically you will read your lines from a file, then it's likely you will use a `Stream`. In that case you may use a method like this:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> ReplaceRepeatedLines(Stream data, Encoding encoding)
{
    var seen = new HashSet<string>();
    using var reader = new StreamReader(data, encoding);
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!seen.Add(line))
        {
            yield return "REPETITION";
        }
        else
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to load everything in memory like that and then do operations on it is less than ideal if you have a large dataset.

If you care about performance, process it line-by-line. Take in your input file as a stream, and write to an output file as a stream so you never keep more than a few KB in memory at a time. And the algorithm is very simple: if the current line equals the previous line, just write REPETITION! to the output stream.

LINQ is great for quick, expressive statements but it shouldn't be used for everything.

Comment: I'm trying with a foreach loop and a Regex instruction, but for very long strings containing different character types, I get a "Too many closing parenthesis" error.

Comment: Why are you using regexes? Can't you compare each line to the previous line directly?

Comment: They're not necessarily adjacent. Therefore, I need nested loops. I instead use Regex to compare the repeated string with the entire string. Unfortunately though, I get those strange error messages.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you'd use regex. Instead, parse line-by-line, and use a dictionary to keep track of lines you've already encountered.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that: a foreach loop going through my dictionary and a nested for-next loop going through all of the original lines. For very large data, this is extremely slow. I'm looking for a way to speed it up.

Comment: The LINQ command in the question above works like a charm in finding and grouping repeated lines. Can't I somehow tweak that to make it work?

Comment: You're welcome to try whatever you want, but I don't see how using LINQ for that application would be easier or more performant.